# How to add <i> element to Html.ActionLink Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi all I am working on MVC project that and I am using a Html.ActionLink in many parts of my project

Like this code

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Continue Shopping", "showItems", "EasySaveInvoices", new object(), new { @class = "btn btn-large" })
```

but I want to add i element in this object like this Code

```
<a href="products.html" class="btn btn-large">
<i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Continue Shopping 
</a>
```

how can I do this in the Html.ActionLink object. 
please anyone can help me.

Comment: You can not change the content of the anchor tag using Html Helper method.  You will have to render the html manually and assign href attribute value .

Answer (score 0):

do this way

```
<a href="@Url.Action('ActionName','COntrollerName')" class="btn btn-large">
<i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Display Name
</a>
```

give your `url` in `href` and pass it manually, you cannot do it inside the Html helpers

Comment: Unfortunately, this code giving a Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: How can I pass it in side Html helper.